# associatedType inside another associatedType using protocols

Tags: swift, generics

I have been struggling to find a solution using generics and associated types inside another associated type for the problem above

### Case

I want to have an `ObjectRequestType`, which inside it has an associated type of type `ObjectResponseType`.

```
protocol ObjectRequestType {
    associatedtype Response: ObjectResponseType
}
```

`ObjectResponseType` on the other hand is a protocol having associated type `Element`

```
protocol ObjectResponseType {
    associatedtype Element
}
```

What I want to achieve is that I want to extend the functionality of `ObjectRequestType` depending on different type of elements, that here for the sake of example we have two different types of `Element`.

```
protocol ElementType {}
protocol OtherElementType {}
```

So far I would implement this by the following extensions

```
extension ObjectRequestType where Response.Element: ElementType {
    static func request() {
        print("ElementType")
    }
}

extension ObjectRequestType where Response.Element: OtherElementType {
    static func request() {
        print("OtherElementType")
    }
}
```

The extra step would be to handle to pass this request to a class which I need using generics

```
class DemoClass<Request: ObjectRequestType> {
    static func execute() {
        Request.request()
    }
}
```

### Problem

Since on the fly `DemoClass` cannot define what kind of `Response` the `Request` has it will find two implementations of it, and it will fail throwing the compilation error

> error: ambiguous reference to member 'request()'

Modifying the class by adding an extra where clause still won't do it, because I will miss the rest of the implementation of `OtherElementType`

```
class DemoClass<Request: ObjectRequestType> where Request.Response.Element: ElementType {
    static func execute() {
        Request.request()
    }
}
```

I have been trying workarounds about it, but still I haven't been able to implement this kind of case. If anybody has any idea or another approach, it would be happily welcomed.

Comment: `Request.Response.Element: ElementType`

Comment: @Kevin thanks, it was a typo, but still see what my issue is there

Comment: Any reason `static func request()` isn't part of the `ObjectRequestType` protocol?

Comment: @Kevin this is the main idea to have `static func request()` providing different implementation depending on the associatedType

Comment: Well, yes, that's what the protocol extension does.  If it's not part of the protocol, there's no guarantee there is even a `request` function on any particular entity implementing `ObjectRequestType`. You could check the types at runtime, but that's terrible style and error prone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usual way to do this is to add the `request` method to the `ObjectResponseType` protocol so you can guarantee that it exists on any conforming type. Then you create a protocol extension providing the default implementation for the types you know how to handle, which you've already done. If you need to override the request for a certain request with one of the existing element types, you can do that. If you need to support another element type, you can either do it right in the request or add another protocol extension.

```
protocol ObjectResponseType {
    associatedtype Element
}
protocol ObjectRequestType {
    associatedtype Response: ObjectResponseType

    static func request()
}

protocol ElementType {}

extension ObjectRequestType where Response.Element: ElementType {
    static func request() {
        print("ElementType")
    }
}
protocol OtherElementType {}
extension ObjectRequestType where Response.Element: OtherElementType {
    static func request() {
        print("OtherElementType")
    }
}

class DemoClass<Request: ObjectRequestType> {
    static func execute() {
        Request.request()
    }
}

class Foo: ElementType {}
class FooResponse: ObjectResponseType {
    typealias Element = Foo
}
class FooRequest: ObjectRequestType {
    typealias Response = FooResponse
}

class Bar: OtherElementType {}
class BarResponse: ObjectResponseType {
    typealias Element = Bar
}
class BarRequest: ObjectRequestType {
    typealias Response = BarResponse
    // Override the default implementation
    static func request() {
        print("Bar")
    }
}

class Baz {}
class BazResponse: ObjectResponseType {
    typealias Element = Baz
}
class BazRequest: ObjectRequestType {
    typealias Response = BazResponse

    static func request() {
        print("Baz")
    }
}

DemoClass<FooRequest>.execute() // ElementType
DemoClass<BarRequest>.execute() // Bar
DemoClass<BazRequest>.execute() // Baz
```